# IdentityServer4, .net Core Web Api; implementing individual user accounts with social logins enabled

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to figure out whether the following is possible and how can it be done:
Implementing individual user accounts login enabled for Web Api in .Net Core using IdentityServer4, providing the following capabilities:
- Generating access tokens,
- Generating refresh tokens,
- Enabling social logins,
- Enabling roll-based authorization
- Using local database for storage (EntityFramework...)

I wasn't able to get this under control using the available documents, I was wondering if anybody has done something similar before or knows where to start.

Comment: by social logins you mean OAuth2?

Comment: I mean like using Google, Facebook, or any other external authentication :)

Answer (score 3):

I've created a proof of concept project. To make a long story short clone the project https://github.com/ChrisRichner/CoreWebApp.Quickstart and start playing with the following features immediately.

- AspNetCore 1.0

  - https Kestrel (uncomment Code for https)
- Thinktecture IdentityServer4

  - AspNetIdentity
  - EntityFrameworkStorage
  - Social Logins (Google, Twitter)
- Swagger

  - IdentityServer OAuth Integration
- Unit Tests based on XUnit

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, following your instructions on github, it throws a "WindowsCryptographicException" when I try to run it. I thought it may be due to the absence of the "idsrv3test.pfx" so I downloaded that and added to your project and still didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the missing file. I'll add it right now